# Vue JS v-bind data doesn't update reactivity in v-footer tag

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Using Vue and vuetify I faced with issue with v-footer element. 
v-bind data doesn't update reactivity in v-footer tag

See code below

```
  <template>
 <div>
  <v-footer class="pa-3">
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <div>© {{ new Date().getFullYear() }}</div>
      <!-- it doesn't work -->
      <p :style="mystyle"> TEST </p>
      <v-btn @click="changeStyle">ChangeStyle</v-btn>
      <!-- it doesn't work -->
  </v-footer> 
      <!-- it works -->
      <p :style="mystyle"> TEST </p>
      <v-btn @click="changeStyle">ChangeStyle</v-btn>
      <!-- it works -->
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        data () {
          return {
            mystyle:{
            opacity : 0, 
            color: 'red'},
          }
        },
       methods: {
          changeStyle(){
        this.mystyle.opacity = 1
    }
       } 
    }
</script>
```

At the same time if I add code {{labelStyle.opacity}} in template all works normaly.

Comment: Please could you update your question to give it a more descriptive title?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
showLabel() {
    this.$set(this.labelStyle, 'opacity', 1);
}
```

Comment: Add some description as to what your code is doing.